# Software to block keyboard of laptop during video conversation

Tags: windows, gratis, keyboard, children

Having a little children in a Skype conversation in a laptop is complicated: they either ignore the screen if it is too far away or start banging the keyboard if it is too close by.

I am looking for some software that can block the keyboard apart from a given key combination. This way, any banging on the keyboard won't resize screens, switch off the video or whatever else can randomly happen.

I have been looking for some software and I see there are some products, like [Key Freeze](http://keyfreeze.com/) and [Kid Key Lock](http://download.cnet.com/Kid-Key-Lock/3000-2132_4-185000.html).

However, I wonder: is there anyone with experience using them?

I need:

- Windows
- To work with Skype

I prefer:

- Free

Comment: How about inverting a plastic tray over the body of the laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have been using Key Freeze for some days now and I can write a review of it: overall it works, even though it is a bit picky.

#### Pros

- It is gratis.
- The installation is super simple.
- It gives you 5 seconds in a countdown to do whatever actions you want before freezing the keyboard and mouse.
- It gets started very easily:

  - you open it.
  - you run it.
- Unblocking is also simple:

  - you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> and then <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

#### Cons

- In Skype, you lose the full screen mode. This means that before running Key Freeze you need to maximize the screen as much as you can.
- Functions keys still work. This means that accidentally pressing the Flight mode makes you lose the connection.

Answer (score 1):

you could try

- [Keyfreeze](http://keyfreeze.com/)
- [Kid-Key-Lock](http://download.cnet.com/Kid-Key-Lock/3000-2132_4-185000.html)
- [Toddler Keys](http://download.cnet.com/Toddler-Keys/3000-27064_4-10305344.html)

As far as I know, all of them are free.